If $R$ has infinitely many maximal ideals in these cases, can the Jacobson radical be nonzero?
All rings assumed to be commutative with 1 and have infinite number of maximal ideals.
In which of the following cases Jacobson radical of $R$ is nonzero?

$R$ is PID
$R$ is UFD
$R$ is an integral domain that each nonzero non-unit element of $R$ is a finite product
of irreducible elements of $R$.


For PID, I can factor any element into finite number of irreducible elements and
any ideal generated by an irreducible element is maximal. So that, in the case of
PIDs, Jacobson radical does not contain a non-zero ideal.
For UFD I dont have proof but i guess it is true, regarding examples like polynomials.
For the 3ed case ?

Any complete or partial answer is welcomed.
Thank you.

What's the source of the problem, by the way?  I've seen partial solutions, but along the lines of Dedekind domains, rather than in the direction of UFDs.

please upload the partial answer. dedekind domain or similar kinds of rings are also interesting

see question 4.5 of this

So... what is the source of your problem?

Thank you very much. it starts with the fact that jacobson rad of Z is 0. then i see that the proof can be generalized for pids. the proof is based on factorization. so it is natural to think about ufds ,....

Are you trying to say "I made this problem up myself"?  Because that will help users gauge whether or not they're engaging with a solvable problem.

Im not aware of all rules of stackexchange. do u mean any question except exercises of books should be warned to users?

Yes, mentioning the source of your problem can be valuable context. A great majority of problems posed and answered appear in books, therefore there is good assurance that they have reasonable answers. On the other end of the spectrum, there are open questions which nobody knows the answer to, which do not make good questions.  If you make up a question then it would be good to say so, and that way people can take that into account before they go on a wild goose chase for what they think might be an exercise in a book.

Here's a construction that gives lots of Noetherian UFDs with infinitely many maximal ideals and non-zero Jacobson radical. (Or if you want, also non-Noetherian UFDs with this property or Noetherian domains with this property that are not UFDs.) Any Noetherian integral domain satisfies your third condition, so this completely answers your question.
Let $R$ be any domain with infinitely many maximal ideals (e.g. $\Bbb Z,k[x]$, whatever you want.) Consider the localization $S^{-1}R[x]$, where $S=1+(x)$. Then the Jacobson radical of $S^{-1}R[x]$ contains $x$: this follows directly from the characterization of the Jacobson radical of a ring $T$ as $J(T)=\{t \in T \mid\forall r\in T:1+rt \in T^\times\}$ and the definition of $S$. In particular, the Jacobson radical of $S^{-1}R[x]$ is non-zero. Because the ideal $(x)$ is contained in the Jacobson radical, maximal ideals of $S^{-1}R[x]$ correspond bijectively to maximal ideals of $S^{-1}R[x]/(x)$. But $S^{-1}R[x]/(x) \cong R$, so $S^{-1}R[x]$ has infinitely many maximal ideals if and only if $R$ has infinitely many maximal ideals.
Finally, if we take $R$ to be Noetherian, then by Hilbert's basis theorem and the fact that Noetherian rings are stable under localization, $S^{-1}R[x]$ is Noetherian as well. If $R$ is a UFD, a variant of Gauss's lemma combined with the fact that the localization of a UFD is a UFD gives that $S^{-1}R[x]$ is a UFD. If we take, say $R=\Bbb Z$ or any other Noetherian UFD, then $S^{-1}R[x]$ will be a Noetherian UFD.
